# Errors with a code to get and put in a tweet the now playing song

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, twitter

[image: The errors]

```
- (IBAction)playingSong {
MPMediaItem *theSong = [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem];
NSString *theTitle   = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
NSString *theArtist  = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
NSString *nowPlaying = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#NowPlaying %@ by %@", theTitle, theArtist];
tweetTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", nowPlaying, tweetTextView.text];
[self setChars];
}

- (IBAction)sendMusicTweet:(id)sender {
    TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [tweetViewController setInitialText:tweetTextView.text];
    [self presentModalViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES];

}
```

I have imported the frameworks. But I don't know how to resolve this errors... What can I do? Thanks :)

Comment: It's declared as 'theSong', not song.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's declared as 'theSong', not song.  You never declared a pointer to tweetTextView in the .h and setChars isn't defined in ANY file.

Your code SHOULD BE:

```
- (IBAction)playingSong {
MPMediaItem *theSong = [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem];
NSString *theTitle   = [theSong valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
NSString *theArtist  = [theSong valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
NSString *nowPlaying = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#NowPlaying %@ by %@", theTitle, theArtist];
//Declare tweetTextView in the .h!!
tweetTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", nowPlaying, tweetTextView.text];
//[self setChars]; Define this In the .h!
}

- (IBAction)sendMusicTweet:(id)sender {
    TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [tweetViewController setInitialText:tweetTextView.text];
    [self presentModalViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES];

}
```